# Terraform how to loop over count (number type)

Tags: loops, count, terraform

I am fairly new to terraform. I have a map that looks like this

```
    { Small: 2, medium: 1 }
```

I need to create a local list that looks like below so I can easily loop over the list to create VMs.

```
    [
       small, 
       small,
       medium
    ]
```

So far, I have tried something like this

```
    ([for k, v in var.webservers : [
        for s in v: v]
    ])
```

My logic was to loop on the count(value) of each key-value pair to generate a list. But TF expects a collection for iteration.

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this as follows:

```
variable "webservers" {
  default = { 
        small = 2, 
        medium = 1
  }
}


output "test" {
  value =  flatten([for k, v in var.webservers : 
             [
               for t in range(v): k
             ]
           ])
    
}
```

The order may be different, but this is because maps do not have order.

Comment: thank you so much. Exactly what I needed!